# Is there a fast way to paste consecutive numbers in multiple selection?

Tags: html, sublimetext2, phpstorm, sublimetext3, sublimetext

When working with HTML ids it is often necessary to create elements with same id names, but different numeric index, for example:

```
<ul>
   <li id="item-|"></li>
   <li id="item-|"></li>
   <li id="item-|"></li>
   <li id="item-|"></li>
   <li id="item-|"></li>
</ul>
```

"|" - represents one of the multiple cursors.
Is there a way to paste numbers from 1-5 there?

Comment: Hmm, no nth-child? (If I need an id number in a sequence it almost always comes from a dynamic generation.)

Comment: No always nth-child can be used. At current project I need different ids for modal windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## For **PhpStorm**:

You can use the [String Manipulation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162) plugin.

To generate numbers in sequence at the [multiple carets](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-source-code.html#multiple_cursor):

1. Type in the number to start the sequence with, say `1`, and then select the number.
2. Open the String Manipulation menu. This is done by

   - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, or
   - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, or
   - *Pull Down Menu* → *Edit* → *String Manipulation*.
3. In the menu, choose *Increment/Decrement* → *Create sequence*.

Here's an animated screenshot:
[image]
*<sup>Screenshot is based on PhpStorm 2016.2 and String Manipulation  5.0.135.445.0.</sup>*

Comment: Late thanks for this solution, as I don't use Sublime anymore. It works magically! And the plugin overall is also very useful.

Answer (score 5):

you can install the emmet plugin for sublime text from the package control.
here is the emmet [cheat sheet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) 
Every web developer used it and saves heck a load of time

---

type **ul>li#item-$*5** and press tab and the whole code will be generated :

```
<ul>
  <li id="item-1"></li>
  <li id="item-2"></li>
  <li id="item-3"></li>
  <li id="item-4"></li>
  <li id="item-5"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I use Emmet a lot and aware of this solution, but was looking for something that doesn't require creating elements from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin called **[insertNums](https://github.com/jbrooksuk/InsertNums)** that does exactly what you are looking for. You can use it to insert a sequence of numbers into the cursors positions.

It also allows you to define some options like the start number and the step between numbers and others.

Comment: Wow! This plugin does EXACTLY what I asked for! Thanks!