# Multicursor in PhpStorm: Is it possible to add consecutive numbers as with Emmet for Html?

Tags: html, phpstorm, text-editor

The multicursor in PhpStorm is extremly useful, when dealing with repeating code.
Now when I use Emmet, I can do the following to produce consecutive numbers:

```
ul>li.myListItem$*5
```

when I press tab, this is replaced by

```
<ul>
    <li class="myListItem1"></li>
    <li class="myListItem2"></li>
    <li class="myListItem3"></li>
    <li class="myListItem4"></li>
    <li class="myListItem5"></li>
</ul>
```

where the dollar is replaced by the numbers. Is there something like that in PhpStorm. My idea would be that I have e.g. the following code:

```
<div class="pictureFrame"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame"> ... </div>
```

and now I want to add ids to the elements. So I put a multicursor over all lines and quickly produce the following:

```
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame"> ... </div>
```

with my multicursor still after the frame word in each line. Now I imagine pressing something like $ and then tab and it would result in

```
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame1"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame2"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame3"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame4"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame5"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame6"> ... </div>
```

unfortunately, with dollar (as in Emmet), it doesn't work. Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129339/is-there-a-fast-way-to-paste-consecutive-numbers-in-multiple-selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what can be done using an additional (3rd party) plugin.

**1.** Install **"String Manipulation" plugin** & restart IDE (plugins are loaded only on start).

**2.** Go to your code, make multiple carets and add `0` as starting numbers:

```
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame0"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame0"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame0"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame0"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame0"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame0"> ... </div>
```

**3.** While multiple carets are still active -- use this action provided by the aforementioned plugin: `Edit | String Manipulation | Increment/Decrement... | Increment to build sequence`

Final result:

```
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame1"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame2"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame3"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame4"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame5"> ... </div>
<div class="pictureFrame" id="frame6"> ... </div>
```

Comment: Man, what a neat plugin :)